# How to have test job in Jenkins to mark build as Stable and NOT Unstable?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, jenkins

Currently I am building and testing my app in Jenkins. If a test fails in the job then the build is marked as Unstable. Is it possible to have the build be marked as Stable even though tests fail? The build is marked as Failed if code does not compile, and that is fine.

Comment: But tests failing indicate the build *is* unstable. If you don't care about the tests failing, then you can set the build not to run them.

Comment: I knew this would be the first comment :) Anyway, I do want to set failing tests to succeed the build, as my main concert first is to make sure that the build and tests compile.

Comment: You don't need Jenkins for that then. You manually run compiles (are you using Maven?) and that tells you. Tests are less than useless if they only compile but don't pass.

Comment: sure I do. I need to make sure tests compile too

Comment: You need them to compile, but you don't care if they pass? you'd be better off deleting them then, as they're less than useless if you're not running them.

Comment: You could just make a job that all it does is compile your tests. I don't know what build tool you are using but we are using SBT. So in Jenkins, I have a job that calls `sbt test:compile`. This commands makes sure the test compiles (doesn't run them). Look in your build tool, I'm sure there is a similar command. If that job passes, then I run individual tests. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a plugin called Jenkins Text Finder:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin

It allows to search console log for regular expression matches, and if found, it can set the build to various states, including setting it as "success" (i.e. not unstable).

Just echo a unique label/line into your console output after the build is successful, and look for that line with this plugin. Use "**Succeed if found**" option in the plugin to mark build successful.

Comment: Thanks @Slav Just installed the plugin and works really nicely. I can now start removing awkward checks at the end of our builds...