# Ignoring certain exceptions to avoid build failure

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm using Cucumber reporting Jenkins plugin (http://www.masterthought.net/section/cucumber-reporting) to show all cucumber results to all stakeholders. The tables display the number of steps passing and pending, which is good : at the beginning of the sprint, I add my scenarios, and all new steps are pending. Little by little, they will pass.

But I face an issue : with cucumber, pending steps are actually throwing a PendingException by default, until we actually implement them. And these PendingExceptions make my Maven build unstable, as they are seen as test failures, which they are not.

So more generally : is there a way to configure Maven in such a way that some exceptions are ignored and my build succeeds ? Ideally, I would like to configure somewhere a list of Exception classes that shouldn't be taken into account : if only PendingException is thrown while executing my test suite, build should be OK and pending steps should show in Cucumber report.

I couldn't find anything so far ; I've looked at surefire, but I would need something more than the testFailureIgnore property : I need to also specify which type of failure I ignore. Did anybody come across this use case before ?

Thanks

Vincent

Comment: Have you considered something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680334/how-to-have-test-job-in-jenkins-to-mark-build-as-stable-and-not-unstable

Comment: yes, I saw this, but I don't think it would work for me as I would need a combination of regexp like "make success if PendingException is found **AND** no other exception is found". I really feel it would be better to configure Surefire to simply not report the failures generated by the configured exception

Answer (score 0):

Actually, specifically for my cucumber reporting issue, I have found the reason why my pending steps make the build fail ; It doesn't answer the generic question of "how to ignore a specific Exception in a build", but it helps with my features reporting.

I usually like to use the strict=true option on my Cucumber tests : this way in the IDE, I know I'm not done until it's green. But  if I want the pending/skipped steps to **not fail** my build, I have to remove the strict option.

I'll explore the possibility of overriding the strict value at build time : if I keep strict=true in my tests for dev time, but I'm able to override the value at build time, that would be great !

Comment: a fast way to accomplish this would be to build a different runner class for your dev options. then you can execute this while testing in your IDE and execute the other runner in your maven build

Comment: is there a way to change the runner at run time ? I usually have @RunWith hardcoded in my test ; I've never seen an example where the runner was dynamically set

Comment: as far as i know there is no easy way to do this, why not do what i mentioned above?

Comment: assume I write my own Runner : I need to mention it in RunWith annotation, right ? so how can I switch dynamically from one runner (in Eclipse) to another (in Maven build) ? I don't think that's possible. And obviously, I don't want to duplicate my test, and have 2 versions of it with different runners configured.

Comment: okay we are not talking on the same level, i was thinking about:       import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
  dryRun = false,
  strict = true,
    plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/cucumber.json", "html:target"},
  features = {"path/to/feature"},
  glue = {"path.to.glue"},
  tags = {"@DevTag"})
public class MyCucumberTestRunner {
  public MyCucumberTestRunner(){}
}   this times two with different strict settings

Comment: OK, I understand what you mean... well, if I'm going to create a second CucumberTestRunner for dev purpose only, just to change the strict flag, then I may as well change **locally** the value of strict flag in the existing CucumberTestRunner, and not commit.

Comment: or you put the second class in your gitignore and dont need to change anything, i am sorry, but i dont have a better solution